# How to change the default selected option in a Django ChoiceField?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to get a form with a choice field in Django. My form code looks like this:

```
UNIVERSITIES = (
    ('North South University', 'North South University'),
    ('BRAC University', 'BRAC University'),
)

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Form used to search for a professor.
    """
    professor_name = forms.CharField(
        label="Enter a professor's name or name code",
        max_length=255,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Search for a professor',
            'required' : 'required',
        }),
    )
    university = forms.ChoiceField(
        label="Select your university",
        choices=UNIVERSITIES,
    )
```

In the form I get 'North South University' by default. How do I change that to an empty string? That is, no option will be selected Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
university = forms.TypedChoiceField(
    label="Select your university",
    choices=UNIVERSITIES,
    empty_value="--- youre empty value here ---",
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
UNIVERSITIES = (
    ( None, ''),
    ('North South University', 'North South University'),
    ('BRAC University', 'BRAC University'),
)
```

Since the value will be `None` by default the user will be required to select one of the options. If you want to change the text to something like `'Select your university'` you can change the `''` to that or you can add a `Label` to the `ChoiceField`.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
On ModelForm I use this method to replace all fields:

```
class SearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Search
        fields = "__all__"
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for f in SearchForm.base_fields.values(): f.empty_label = f.label
```

Method 2: On ModelForm I use this method to replace only one field:

```
class SearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Search
        fields = "__all__"
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['university'].empty_label = "Label"
```